# SQL Date formatting for Excel pivot tables

Tags: sql, excel, date, pivot, pivot-table

I'm pulling data to use in a Pivot table in Excel, but Excel is not recognizing the date format.

I'm using..

```
CONVERT(date, [DateTimeSelected]) AS [Search Date]
```

Which shows as as **2013-08-01** in my query output.

When it get to into my Excel pivot table via my SQL Connection it looks the same but the filters do not recognize as a date.

Here you can see how Excel is see it as text on the left and n the right what it should look like in Excel when it recognizes it as a date.

[image]

Any ideas please?

Thanks ;-)

Tried all these but only the original B.Depart (date time) comes through as a date, none of the converted columns are read by Excel as a date...

I get loads of formats but Excel must not like converted dates??

```
 B.Depart AS 'Holiday Date time',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B.Depart,103) AS 'Holiday Date',
 DATENAME(weekday, B.Depart) AS 'Holiday Day Name',
 CONVERT(CHAR(2), B.Depart, 113) AS 'Holiday Day',
 CONVERT(CHAR(4), B.Depart, 100) AS 'Holiday Month',
 CONVERT(CHAR(4), B.Depart, 120) AS 'Holiday Year',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.Depart,10) AS 'New date',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),B.Depart),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.Depart,10),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.Depart,110),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),B.Depart,6),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),B.Depart,106),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),B.Depart,113)
```

Comment: I've tried everything here but all dates, apart from the original B.Depart (date time), are read by Excel as text and sorted alpha by filters when pulled through using the SQL connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is appears that `cast(convert(char(11), Bo.Depart, 113) as datetime)` works..

Comment: After applying this, I then found I could change the date formats for the PivotTable, but not the PivotChart. Even 'linking to source' wouldn't pull through any formatting changes any changes. To re-format the dates on your axis after applying this solution, you must go through **PivotChart Fields > Field Settings > Number Format**. Any changes to the format here will change your date axis label format.

Answer (score 2):

I found the only answer for me was to set the SQL data as source for a Table, rather than a pivot table, and then build a pivot table from that Table.

That was I was able to apply the Number format to the Pivot table Row Labels, and that allowed me to format the date how I wanted on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Important to note that if the dates are first recognized as text, and *then* you change the query to one of the suggestions, you'll have to tell Excel to not retain the old text-formatted values in the Pivot Table cache (Pivot tables by default retain 'old' values in each field in the cache in the background, even if they're not in the data currently being returned). Otherwise, since the first values are still in the cache (even though they are no longer in the live data), the whole field gets recognized as text.

For example, I had an existing table where I was having this problem. I changed my query to use Mike's post of

cast(convert(char(11), Bo.Depart, 113) as datetime)

, but it didn't actually result in Excel recognizing it as a date until after I reset the items retained in the Pivot Table cache.

To change how the Pivot Table retains items in the Cache,
1. Right-click on the Table
2. Choose 'Pivot Table Options'
3. On 'Data' tab, change drop-down menu for 'Number of items to retain per field' to 'None'.

This is also useful when your slicer buttons show values that are no longer in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Excel 2010.
My solution was to specify the connection type to the SQL Server as 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' rather than 'SQL Server' (available in the advanced/other selection in the data connection guide). Using that everything worked fine connecting to sql server tables containing standard date formatted columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SmallDatetime` format in your SQL table and will work. Never convert dates as varchar.